# python pip error during installation CalledProcessError

Tags: installation, pip, subprocess, python-3.5

I'm using python3.5(32bit) on windows 7  and have pip installed but everytime i want to install something using pip (also with pip3 and pip3.5) this error occurs:
(It also happens when i try to use the wheel files for installation)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 174, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 133, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\download.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\_vendor\distro.py", line 1040, in <module>
    _distroi = LinuxDistribution()
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\_vendor\distro.py", line 591, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
  File "C:\Users\jmh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages
\pip-8.2.0.dev0-py3.5.egg\pip\_vendor\distro.py", line 925, in _lsb_release_info

   raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(rc, cmd, err)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit s
tatus 1
```

I would really appreciate your help, because it is very time consuming to always search for binaries or build packages from source, where also other stuff might come up etc.. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pip already?

Comment: I have tried it with the get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ but i get this: (Shortened)

Comment: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,read=None,redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionEror'...
No connection could be made because the target machine acitvely refused it...
Requirement already uptodate: pip in c:\...
Collecting wheel
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,read=None,redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionEror'...
No connection could be made because the target machine acitvely refused it...
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel..
no matching distributions found for wheel